# Discovered two anonymous users with identical gravatars... in the same question (SO)

Tags: support, stack-overflow, gravatar

As the title states, I found [both](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225714/user225714) [users](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213199/user213199) involved in [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348897/iphonehow-can-create-a-game-like-tossring-app-released-recently).

Is this a byproduct of not entering an e-mail address combined with random coincidence? Have I stumbled upon a situation of possible future collusion?

There is little evidence to go on at this point (both seem to be involved in roughly the same subject area, but both have < 20 rep), so maybe this is just something to keep tabs on.

Comment: If they have no given email and the same IP the gravatars will be identical.

Comment: Not colleagues I hope, given both were online during the last hours, on Sunday ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither has an e-mail, and they share an IP - but there is no inappropriate activity *between* the accounts. They *might* be the same person, or they might be friends / colleagues. Who knows? Let them be, I reckon...

Comment: And two different names, whatever that means, so I guess it's not about forgetting an earlier login either. (Dave and Prabakar)

Comment: @Arjan - indeed; they're both registered accounts.

Comment: Just in case someone wonders where I saw the names: I meant to say they use different names below their posts. Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751315/iphonecan-my-program-access-camera-using-imagepicker-api and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348897/iphonehow-can-create-a-game-like-tossring-app-released-recently

Comment: Marc correct me if I'm wrong but the official policy is that sock puppets are allowed as long as you don't upvote yourself (or similar), right?

Comment: @Koper - I'm not sure about *official* but that *sounds* reasonable. Same reason *not* to have a flagging-user function. It's not about the users, it's their behavior that can be inappropriate.

Comment: I believe that sock puppets are verbally discouraged for any purpose, but action won't be taken unless you causing trouble or trying to cheat. In any case I think we need enough policy flexibility for people to maintain accounts for (say) observing the new user experience.

Comment: I don't think we should tolerate sock puppets ever -- if someone wants to have one for a legitimate research purpose, they should have to clear it with the moderators explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, Marc. I'll take a peek at this periodically.